# can't get JS to correctly evaluate two identical strings

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I can see in the log that there are multiple matches during the loop but it's only returning true (and adding the file to the array) on the last iteration. 'typeof' is telling me they are all strings and they look identical in the console. can't figure what would make JS not see them as identical.

Would spaces or square brackets cause problems?

```
var name = file.split('.');
for (l=0;l<d.length;l++)
{
  var n = d[l].split('.');
  var r = n[0].replace(/\[\d\]$/,''); //chop off last bracket in file name

  // tells me both variables are strings
  console.log('r is a: ' + (typeof r) + ' name is a: ' + (typeof name[0]));

  if(r && r == name[0])
  {
    count_array.push(r);
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' + r + ' added to array');
  }
}
```

Thx!

Comment: What does `console.log('r is: ' + r + ', name is: ' + name[0]);` give?

Comment: But both **are** strings. Just because they are strings doesn't make them equal. Also, where did `d` come from?

Comment: All this does is compare two strings. The two strings just happen to be file names but as for as the 'if' is concerned they are just strings.

Comment: also, name[0] is a user selected file name sans the extension and r represents each file as it loops thru the directory(d)...also without it's extension. if a file or files matches the selected file it adds it to the array.

Comment: A good debugging step would be to add a line right before `if(r && r == name[])` and send those values to the console rather then just checking the types ... make there's something that should match, and perhaps put that output in your question.

Comment: Thanks Erik, that was step 1. step 2 was checking the type to make sure they were strings. here's the console anyway(ugly,sry). You can see two matches but only the last was added to the array.


    [INFO] AAAA7x == Note 2

    [INFO] Empty folder == Note 2

    [INFO] Folder One == Note 2

    [INFO] Note 2 == Note 2
    [INFO] Note 2 == Note 2
    [INFO] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Note 2 added to array
    [INFO] Note 2b == Note 2
    [INFO] Real text == Note 2
    [INFO] Save for new what == Note 2
    [INFO] Save for new == Note 2
    [INFO] Song_1 == Note 2

Answer (score 1):

Your question is, er, far from clear. But a stab in the dark, you have this line:

```
var r = n[0].replace(/\[\d\]$/,''); //chop off last bracket in file name
```

That will remove a paired set of brackets with **one** digit in-between them, so for instance `foo[1]` => `foo`. It won't remove a paired set of brackets with two or more digits in-between them, like say `foo[10]` => `foo`. For that, you'd want:

```
var r = n[0].replace(/\[\d+\]$/,''); //chop off last bracket in file name
//                        ^--- Added the +
```

Comment: Thanks T.J., I def updated that line, but unfortunately that's not the culprit.